# simple html dom unable to handle forward slash in find(id)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

find() here is a function of the simple_html_dom library, that should return dom node elements when given an id/class.

`$urlFetched->find("#".$id)` always fails to find and return something when the $id is "fk-list-MP3-Players-/-IPods". I am guessing the problem is with the forward slash and simple_html_dom, because there is no problem with the other ids and urls(snipped).
What do I do? my program is almost complete and dependent on simple html dom.

Thanks

The code:

```
$urlAndIds = array(
   array("http://www.flipkart.com/audio"  , array('fk-list-Home-Audio', htmlentities("fk-list-MP3-Players-/-IPods"), 'fk-list-Accessories'),array('ALL','AllBrands')) );

foreach($urlAndIds as $uAI) {
    $url = file_get_contents($uAI[0]) ;
    $urlFetched = str_get_html($url) ;

    if ($url == false){
         echo 'page '.$uAI[0] . " not found"  ."<br>" ."<br>";
    }   else {
        foreach ($uAI[1] as $id) {
            $idFound = $urlFetched->find("#".$id) ;
            if(!$idFound) {

                echo 'In page '.$uAI[0].' -id not found- '.$id  ."<br>";
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I didn't think you could have forward slashes in an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is being interpreted as part of the XPath expression, so it's looking for a child element named `-IPods`.  There is no XPath "quote" type function either.  I'm not sure whether adding a backslash would work, but it may be easier for you to just use a normal attribute selector with id: `[@id='fk-list-MP3-Players-/-IPods']`

Comment: "@[id=fk-list-MP3-Players-/-IPods]" is what worked! Thanks a lot